# tarring a file with shell not working

Tags: shell

I'm trying to tar a two files into one, so I have this:

```
tar -zcvfW "${DATADIR}daily_data_files/LeveL_EOD_VOL_${1}.tar.gz" -C "${DATADIR}temp/LeveL_EOD_VOL_*_${1}.csv" >> "${DATADIR}temp/email.log"
```

However, I'm getting these errors:

```
tar: Removing leading '/' from member names
tar: /var/www/vhosts/levelats/data/daily_data_files/LeveL_EOD_VOL_20110121.tar.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: LeveL_EOD_VOL_*_20110121.csv: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

I'm not sure why the tar isn't getting created, is it because it can't find the two Level_EOD files? Is the wildcard(*) wrong?

Comment: Yes, the `*` is wrong. Inside quotes it will not be expanded by the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening is that the `-C` option is trying to change directory into the first directory expanded by your glob pattern; I think you want:

```
tar -zcvfW "${DATADIR}daily_data_files/LeveL_EOD_VOL_${1}.tar.gz" -C "${DATADIR}temp/" "LeveL_EOD_VOL_\*_${1}.csv" >> "${DATADIR}temp/email.log"
```

Note that I split the `-C` option from the list of CSV files that comes after it.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the option flags is significant (at least the `f` needs to precede the filename). Try changing from `-zcvfW` to `-zcvWf`.

Also `-C` takes a directory as an argument.

Comment: doing this gives me tar: Cannot verify compressed archives

Comment: @Magicmarkker: As Brian suggested, you also need to change the quoting so the globbing works: `"${DATADIR}temp/LeveL_EOD_VOL_"*"_${1}.csv"`. I think that message means the options are mutually exclusive, but I couldn't find documentation to that effect.